# How can I change a file's creation date in Go?

Tags: go, filesystems

Can I change a file's creation time (apparently also known as *birth time* or *btime*) in Go, and if so, how?

I've found a couple of ways to deal with file times in Go, including `os.Chtimes` and [this package](https://github.com/djherbis/times) — however, the former does not support btime, and the latter seems to deal only with reading the dates, not changing them.

I'm looking for a Windows solution, though a general answer won't hurt either.

Comment: I always used os.Chtimes() and that worked fine and I always used the time of last modification, when working with timestamps of files. The timestamps of files are also related to the filesystem. So why is it not possible for you to use mtime?

Comment: @apxp I guess using mtime is an option, it's just not my preferred one - mtime and btime mean different things after all, and I'd like to keep them separate.

Comment: You can't really have a general solution since most OSes don't have a concept of "btime". Windows just calls it "creation time" in the [`SetFileTime` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx), which is available in the syscall package.